# Retrieving card data in card-badges

Tags: trello, trello-powerup

I have an overlay and I'm able to save data using

```
t.set('card', 'shared', 'key', 'value')
```

Also i'm able to read that data using

```
return Promise.all([
    t.get('card', 'shared', 'key1'),
    t.get('card', 'shared', 'key2') 
  ])
  .spread(function(key1, key2){
```

My problem is that I want to read those values from the TrelloPowerUp.initialize and inside the card-badges

I tried using

var x = t.get('card', 'shared', 'key1');

If I put console.log(x), the value is in there but is inside an object and can't make it work. The name of the property is _settledValue

I already tried x.getValue() and x.value()

[file.png](https://postimg.org/image/43ebapqtj/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, answer myself

```
t.get('card', 'shared', 'var_name').then(function(var_name){ /* operations with var_name here */ }
```